# Can't embed GoogleVis in Google Sites through Google Gadget

Tags: r, google-sites, google-gadget, googlevis

I am trying without any success to embed a motion chart created through `googleVis` package. As an example, I'm trying to replicate the same motion chart at:

http://takahashik.blogspot.com.br/2011/01/googlevis-example-for-data-iris_10.html

I'm using the following script:

```
r <- gvisMotionChart(iris, "Species", "time")
plot(r) # just to check that the chart is working properly

gadget = createGoogleGadget(r)

cat(gadget, file="gadget.html")
```

Then I am uploading the `gadget.html` file to my dropbox and generating a link to share it publicly. In my google site I open the page I want to embed the chart into and do the following:
`Insert -> More Gadgets -> Add gadget by URL` and then when I paste the dropbox link to it,
I get the following error:

```
Unsupported feature: org.apache.shindig.common.xml.XmlException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference. At: (13,51)
```

So I checked this error and the general solution I've been seeing is to replace any `&` with `&amp;` in the html code for whatever the reason (I've never worked with html or anything similar). I do get the same error doing that though. I replace the `&`in my file, upload it again, share it, etc and the same error keeps showing up.

```
Unsupported feature: org.apache.shindig.common.xml.XmlException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference. At: (13,51)
```

Any simple solution for this?

Comment: Can you share the gadget.html file?

Comment: Hey, Jasper, thanks for commenting! The file can be downloaded at [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ncmkdf3hagmhmof/myGadget.xml)